# Shoulda-matchers test with FactoryGirl, password_confirmation not set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I am testing my account model with shoulda-matchers using a entity created with FactoryGirl.

The code of both files look like this:

**TEST FILE**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Account do
  before { @account = FactoryGirl.build(:account) }
  subject { @account }

  it { should validate_presence_of(:email) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:password) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:password_confirmation).
        with_message(@account.password_confirmation+' '+@account.password) }
  it { should allow_value('example@domain.com').for(:email) }

  it { should be_valid }
end
```

**FACTORY**

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :account do
    email { FFaker::Internet.email }
    password "12345678"
    password_confirmation "12345678"
  end

end
```

My error is the following:

```
1) Account should require password_confirmation to be set
  Failure/Error: it { should validate_presence_of(:password_confirmation).
   Expected errors to include "12345678 12345678" when password_confirmation is set to nil, got errors: ["password_confirmation can't be blank (nil)"]
 # ./spec/models/account_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'


rspec ./spec/models/account_spec.rb:9 # Account should require password_confirmation to be set
```

I am using devise which should check for password confirmation. I know its probably because of something stupid, but I really can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise, doesn't validate the presence of `password_confirmation` it just validates the confirmation of password see `Validatable` line 34: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v3.5.3/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L34

```
validates_confirmation_of :password, if: :password_required?
```

EDIT: You could also see that there are no validators on password_confirmation running: `User.validators_on(:password_confirmation)`

Comment: As expected, it was something very stupid. :P
Thank you very much ! I added a validator on the model and it works perfectly!

Comment: You shouldn't have to add a validator to make your tests pass, the confirmation alone should do the trick requiring the password_confirmation to be set when the password is being changed and the password is required.

Comment: What do you suggest then? @Leito

Comment: Strictly speaking, that you shouldn't test for code you didn't write. Devise tests for those validations already, if you want to document your expectations with your tests: I suggest you test for the confirmation validation, rather than the presence.